# CAP - Gateway Timeout - How to increase the time out of incoming request

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk, sap-cloud-foundry, sap-cap

I trigger a Post Function Import (Action in CDS), this would typically take about 2 minutes for processing. The POST operation was successfully completed in JAVA, however I get a Gateway Timeout.

How to increase the timeout of incoming requests? I had tried to set the property INCOMING_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT: 0 in mta.yaml of service project as well as using the command

```
cf set-env x-service-name-blue INCOMING_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT 0
cf restage x-service-name-blue
```

It did not work either. 
Could you assist?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** I think the correct environment variable on the approuter is called `SESSION_TIMEOUT`. Can you try this one instead?

---

This is for the XS Advanced approuter, though I'm not sure if it still applies to the one used for CF apps, [this documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4505d0bdaf4948449b7f7379d24d0f0d/2.0.03/en-US/0aac697f0cf7444193ed5eb0fc6e5bd0.html) suggest that it's a property of the approuter, so you can try setting it there.

Comment: I had tried to set this in the approuter, it does not work. if the response time is more than 30 seconds, it results in Status Code: 504 Gateway Timeout. Could you provide any alternate approach?

Comment: Hi @BenuMariantony - if you are using SAP Cloud Platform destinations, the "ClientReadTimeout" destination parameter can be added and increased to 5 minutes (written in ms: 300000). The default is 30s (30000), so this could be what you're running up against.